# Getting ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT while connecting to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hosting, mern, mongodb-atlas

I have created my mongoDb database in mongoDb Atlas and was trying to connect to server(node.js). But I'm unable to connect to my database.`ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` error is showing in the server log. Plaese find the error log below.

```
return new error_1.MongoNetworkError(err);
                   ^

MongoNetworkError: Socket connection timeout
    at connectionFailureError (D:\MERN\Project\social-media-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\MERN\Project\social-media-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:626:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  cause: Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1099:20)
      at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
    code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
  },
  connectionGeneration: 18,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
}

Node.js v20.1.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

`MONGODB_URL = "mongodb+srv://<username here>:<password here>@clustername.bwmogva.mongodb.net/<database name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`

I have tried below options :

`useNewUrlParser : true, socketTimeoutMS : 3000,`

Also tried socketTimeout to `30000`. Checked the network settings in `Atlas`. Gave network access for all network. Still getting the same error. I'm able to connect to database via `MongoDB compass`. It would be great if anyone can help me rectify the problem.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved! I think it was a bug in node version. I have updated node version to v20.7.0. I was using an older version.